# Processing using json as input

Tags: json, variables, processing

I have a processing file which tries to draw an ellipse with the radius depending on a variable.

Now I want to not simply define the variable in the processing file but instead import the value from a json file.

I have tried the following:

```java
JSONObject json;

void setup() {
  size(500,500);

  json = loadJSONObject("data.json");

  int max = json.getInt("max");
  int avg = json.getInt("avg");
  int min = json.getInt("min");

  print(max);
}

void draw() {
 ellipse(10,10,max,min);
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the error: max cannot be resolved to a variable.

Also here how the json file looks. data.json:

```java
[{
    "Max Temperature": {
      "max": "18", 
      "avg": "6", 
      "min": "-2"
    }
  }
 ]
```

Comment: What language are you using to write your code?

Comment: @LearningPhase Notice the [tag:processing] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`loadJSONObject()`](https://www.processing.org/reference/loadJSONObject_.html) function.

Here's an example from the reference:

```
// The following short JSON file called "data.json" is parsed 
// in the code below. It must be in the project's "data" folder.
//
// {
//   "id": 0,
//   "species": "Panthera leo",
//   "name": "Lion"
// }

JSONObject json;

void setup() {

  json = loadJSONObject("data.json");

  int id = json.getInt("id");
  String species = json.getString("species");
  String name = json.getString("name");

  println(id + ", " + species + ", " + name);
}

// Sketch prints:
// 0, Panthera leo, Lion
```

**Edit:** Notice the difference in this example JSON and your JSON. Your JSON contains **one field** named `Max Temperature`. That field is itself a `JSONObject` which contains 3 fields: `max`, `avg`, and `min`.

To get to the `max` field, you have to first go through the "outer" JSONObject. It might look something like this:

```
JSONObject json = loadJSONObject("data.json");
JSONObject maxTemperature = json.getJSONObject("Max Temperature");
int max = maxTemperature.getInt("max");
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://www.processing.org/reference/JSONObject.html).

Comment: yes i found that example on the processing site, but when i try to draw an ellipse (id, 10, 10, 10) then it tells me: The variable "id" does not exist

Comment: @malina Please post a [mcve] that contains the code you tried and the full text of the error. But notice that the example from the reference is just an **example**. You'll have to change the code so that it applies to your JSON. Your JSON does not have an `id` variable.

Comment: dear Kevin, obviously I created the data.json which is mentioned in the example. Also I tried to be as "minimal" as possible, just like as "complete" as it is until now, and I am also quiet sure that my question is specific. so...

Comment: @malina It's really hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions. Stack Overflow is designed more for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. I'd like to help, but I can't do that without seeing exactly what you've tried. Describing it doesn't really work. I need to be able to copy and paste exactly what you've tried and see the exact same thing as you.

Comment: I am sorry kevin you are right, I must have edited out some details by accident. I updated my post and I hope now it should be clear. Sorry again.

Comment: I copied you re code but i am getting the following error: A JSONObject must begin with {

Comment: @malina Your JSON is contained by square brackets `[]`, which means that it's a JSONArray. You either need to get rid of those brackets, or you need to load your data as a JSONArray instead of a JSONObject.

Comment: Thanks, I know where I am heading now. I still cant then in void draw use "max" as a variable, but I will figure it out! Thank you

Comment: @malina That sounds like a **scope** problem. If you want to use the `max` variable in both your `setup()` and `draw()` functions, then you need to **declare** it at the sketch level, not inside the `setup()` function.